# high val-loss and MSE

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have a really big dataset on energy waves and I'm practicing the Neural Network on it, but my MSE and Val-loss are extremely high.
i tried to use correlation matrix and having two step for splitting and i used 3 hidden layers and regularization. the mse and the val oss has a high result about 12 trillion.
[this is the link of my data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/882/large-scale+wave+energy+farm)

```
# Load the data
perth_49 = pd.read_csv(r'WEC_Perth_49.csv')
sydney_49 = pd.read_csv(r'WEC_sydney_49.csv')
perth_100 = pd.read_csv(r'WEC_perth_100.csv')
sydney_100 = pd.read_csv(r'WEC_sydney_100.csv')

#merge the dataframes based on a common identifier
merged_data = pd.concat([perth_49, sydney_49, perth_100, sydney_100])

#define the target variable "total power otput"
target_variable = 'Total_Power'

# Defne the potential features 
features = [f'X{i}' for i in range(1, 101)] + [f'Y{i}' for i in range(1, 101)] + [f'Power{i}' for i in range(1, 101)] + ['qW']

# Compute the correlation matrix
correlation_matrix = merged_data[features + [target_variable]].corr()

# Sort the correlations with the target variable in descending order
correlation_with_target = correlation_matrix[target_variable].sort_values(ascending=False)

print("Correlation with target variable:")
print(correlation_with_target)

# Choose the top N features with the highest correlation
top_features = correlation_with_target.head(5).index.tolist()
top_features = top_features[1:5]  # Exclude the target variable itself

# Select the relevant features from the dataset
selected_data = merged_data[top_features + [target_variable]]

# Replace NaN values with 0 in selected_data
 #selected_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Scale the features (normalizing)
selected_data[top_features] = scale(selected_data[top_features])

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X = selected_data[top_features].values
y = selected_data[target_variable].values.reshape(-1, 1)

# Split the data into training, validation, and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Print the sizes of each set
print("Training set size:", len(X_train))
print("Validation set size:", len(X_val))
print("Testing set size:", len(X_test))

# Scaling the features using MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val_scaled = scaler.transform(X_val)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Creating a neural network with Keras
#model = keras.Sequential([
#    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(len(top_features),)),
#    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
#    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
#    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
#    layers.Dense(1)  # a single output (total power)
#])
##########
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(len(top_features),), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    layers.Dense(1)  # a single output (total power)
])

# Compiling the model
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

# Early stopping
#early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights= True)

# Training the model
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=4000, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_val_scaled, y_val))

# Training the model with early stopping
#model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=4000, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_val_scaled, y_val), callbacks=[early_stopping])


# Evaluating the model on the test set
loss = model.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test)
print("Test Loss:", loss)

# Making predictions
predictions = model.predict(X_test_scaled)

# Calculating mean squared error
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions)
print("Mean Squared Error:", mse)
```

Comment: did you try scaling the response (y) as well? Also, if the variances in your data are not important, apply the scaling after reading the data and before feature selection. It is worth to note that computational methods struggle with very big and very small values, which is why scaling at an early stage is very important.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that for the 4k epochs you may have a combination of too low a learning rate and too deep a network. I am running on a single desktop machine, so will not get through all 4k epochs for 7 days at my current rate, but at epoch 60 I am getting a loss of 777billion with a learning rate of 0.001 and just the first hidden layer. Yes, more hidden layers allows the learning of more complex functions, and a lower learning rate can help with getting a smoother learning but both require more training reps to get a particular level of result. If you have a faster computer then me, it might be worth trying the smaller network and the higher learning rate to see what you manage.

Edit: I have just done some small batch tests for your comparison:

```
100 epochs with set up as described above:  
Test Loss: 490669342720.0
Mean Squared Error: 490669524959.7527


100 epochs with first 2 hidden layers and learning rate=0.1:
Test Loss: 388628578304.0
Mean Squared Error: 388628638043.2276


100 epochs with first 2 hidden layers, learning rate=1:
Test Loss: 449328513024.0
Mean Squared Error: 449328481916.0099
```